# Как узнать битрейт аудио-потока в приложении?

Tags: android, аудио, metadata

Имеется android приложение, в котором можно слушать через интернет различные радиостанции. Как можно показывать пользователю битрейт проигрываемой станции?

В качестве "плеера" в приложении используется библиотека Exoplayer (Если это важно).

Можно примеры кода, как выдернуть и показать битрейт, например из этого url-потока радиостанции (заранее спасибо!) :

http://blackstarradio.hostingradio.ru:8024/blackstarradio128.mp3

Answer (score 1):

Самый правильный способ: замерять потребляемый трафик в секунду, помножить на 8 и разделить на 1000. Это будет примерное количество килобит. Первые 64кб лучше всего отбросить, там может быть так называемый бёрст, или вообще мерять по потребляемым данным декодера, не забывая, что реальный битрейт может меняться каждую секунду.

Способы похуже: искать значения битрейта в метаданных, в адресах. Но там может быть что угодно, хотя бы потому, что реальный битрейт может меняться.

Comment: @bullojot, можно если не трудно пример или ссылку про информацию о замере потребляемого траффика в секунду?

Comment: Ссылаюсь на себя, занимаюсь программированием и работой радиостанции не первый год. Как это сделать с экзоплеером понятия не имею, всегда пишу код сам.

Comment: я думаю надо вам написать собственную реализацию DataSource, отнаследовавшись от основного http источника и перехватить на низком уровне получение байтов.